# JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean:

Tags: java, jasper-reports

When generating an ireport from a jpql, the following exception raises:
JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: .

Yes, getters/setters are ok and I suspect that the source of this cause can be the type  of the collection received by the report: Vector instead a List.

My environment is Java 8, JPA 2.1, itext 2.1.0 and jasper 6.2.0. The method below should return a List, but a Vector is returned. (Vector is a List), used to fill datasource.

```
  public List<Aluno> listarAlunoPorAnoSerie(String ano, Serie serie) {
    List<Aluno> lista = null;
    try {
      EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
      TypedQuery<Aluno> qry = em.createNamedQuery("Aluno.findByAnoSerie", Aluno.class);
      qry.setParameter("ano_letivo", ano);
      qry.setParameter("serie_id", serie.getId());
      lista = qry.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception nre) {
      logger.error(nre.getMessage(), nre);
    }
    return lista;    
  }


JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorio, parametros, beanCollectionDataSource);  // problem
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What is in that list you make DataSource from? How are you using that in your report? What do you mean by "generating an ireport from a jpql"?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It´s List<Student> list. I have tested with a native query and with a jpql. In both, exception is the same.

Comment: What I meant was - could you give something closer to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As you can probably expect what you're trying to do should work. That means that you did something wrong in what you're not showing us. Which is everything, since the only thing you DID show are program versions and two lines of code.